# unresolved call 'init' in Domain Map Class when implementing DSI

Tags: chapel

(chpl version 1.16.0.e43acc7)

I'm starting to learn the [DSI interface](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/technotes/dsi.html) and have run into a confusing issue when constructing a Domain class from the dsiNewRectangularDom function in the Distribution class:

```
class MyDist : BaseDist {

  proc MyDist( fold_dimensions ...?dims ){ }

  proc dsiNewRectangularDom(param rank: int, type idxType, param stridable: bool, inds) {
    var dom = new MyDom( rank=rank, idxType=idxType, stridable=stridable, dist=this);
    return dom;
  }
}

class MyDom : BaseRectangularDom { }

class MyArr : BaseArr { }

config const n = 4;
config const m = 8;
const base_domain = {1..#n,1..#m};
const mapped_domain = base_domain dmapped MyDist( 1 );
```

(This is very basic code, and I don't expect it to fully compile, but I'm stuck on this part.)

This produces the compile error:

```
file.chpl:5: In function 'dsiNewRectangularDom':
file.chpl:6: error: unresolved call 'MyDom.init(rank=2, idxType=type int(64), stridable=0, dist=MyDist)'
file.chpl:11: note: candidates are: MyDom.init(_arrs, _arrs_containing_dom: int(64), _arrsLock: atomicbool, _free_when_no_arrs: bool, pid: int(64), param rank: int(64), type idxType, param stridable: bool)
```

(see [this TIO instance](https://tio.run/##VVFNa8MwDL3nVwh2acAECjuMhDA2et0OY/eixG5r5i9sd10J@e2ZnDTe6oMsWU9PenJ/QifUNPUKQ4C3606GCDW8YhCzOxQFgPO2v@U2cLCK77nUwgRpTYCqqp4pDFAOMGY0D/JdXD5EH9Eczwr9zuqNQ48aPJqvGqSJDOLVCZD855NuBks6RC85dkrU0FmrGCF5KGkQoPONHrjV0IIRlzQSsc6EbTJs5WozZ2Zrs8eAk5A2nmQom5nVi3j2JhGneCxIRt4HNVvWca8FZrEr6sX7Gyp5S8qagzwCXbRFQwM/NvdvScTT/EZBR6V76o8yQYdtVT0YlqweV4hG5wT/A/0v4Usy/9EWymaafgE))

I'm a bit confused about where this init function comes from.
I'm following the behavior of Block, BlockDist, and BlockDom (in particular [BlockDist.chpl:533](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/1.16.0/modules/dists/BlockDist.chpl#L533)
where Block.dsiNewRectangularDom calls BlockDom's constructor.
Since MyDom inherits from BaseRectangularDom, I (1) don't need to declare the rank, idxType, etc member variables, and (2) don't need to define the MyDom( rank, idxType, ... ) constructor.
I also don't see a BlockDom.init function that I could learn from.

What am I missing?

Comment: With respect to this question, I'll mention that I've been mulling over the possibility of writing a "So you want to write your own domain map?" tutorial that would take one through the process step-by-step, growing the interface incrementally, and therefore the set of features a client program can use.  If this would be of interest to you, please open a Chapel GitHub "feature request" issue along these lines to lend more weight to it (and indicate whether you consider it a "blocking issue" or not in the text or a follow-up comment).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most immediate problem is that `BaseRectangularDom` (and therefore `MyDom`) does not have a field named 'dist'. Like `BlockDom`, you'll want to add a 'dist' field, probably like:

```
var dist : MyDist;
```

Once you fix that, you'll be on to the next error (dsiAssignDomain is not implemented).

The error message likely mentioned 'init' as a side effect of the ongoing conversion from constructors to [initializers](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/technotes/initializers.html).